# FMT rules - stay longer than 6 months?

Tags: visas, mexico, visa-runs, fmm-tourist-card

Can I (a Canadian) stay longer in Mexico (longer than 6 months) on a Tourist visa if I leave Mexico, and say go to Belize for a couple days, and return on another 6 month FMT?  In turn, stay for almost a year on a tourist visa?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, as soon as you leave the country for more than 24 hours every 6 months. You can spend some time in Belize, which is safe in touristic places.

I live in Mérida (near Cancún) and I have friends from Belize, Turkey and El Salvador that exit every 5 or 6 months to "refill" their time.

Comment: +1 When we moved to Mexico (as residents) our friend came with us and was **advised by the Mexico consulate** (as she couldn't get residency) that she could live here using this method, renewing the Tourist permit every 6 months.  She has been here now more than 2 years doing this.